# Find index of the first and/or last value in a column that is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am dealing with sub-surface measurements from a borehole where each measurement type covers a different range of depths.  Depth is being used as the index in this case.

I need to find the depth (index) of the first and/or last occurrence of data (non-NaN value) for each measurement type.

Getting the depth (index) of the first or last row of the dataframe is easy: `df.index[0]` or `df.index[-1]`.  The trick is in finding the index of the first or last non-NaN occurrence of any given column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[500, np.NaN, np.NaN,     25],
                   [501, np.NaN, np.NaN,     27],
                   [502, np.NaN,     33,     24],
                   [503,      4,     32,     18],
                   [504,     12,     45,      5],
                   [505,      8,     38, np.NaN]])
df.columns = ['Depth','x1','x2','x3']
df.set_index('Depth')
```

[image]

The ideal solution would produce an index (depth) of 503 for the first occurrence of x1, 502 for the first occurrence of x2, and 504 for the last occurrence of x3.

Comment: But how do you decide that for `'x3'` it needs to be the [last valid index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html) and not the [first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html)?

Comment: The first or last valid index needs to be known for each variable.  The trick is that calling the first or last row index of `df` cannot be used as a work-around when a column has `NaN` values.

Comment: What does your expected output look like? List? Dataframe? Series?

Comment: The expected output would be most easily visualized as a dataframe listing each variable and its maximum & minimum depths.  It would also be convenient to be able to call the values with the format `depth_df['x1']['min']` or `depth_df['x3']['max']`.  Thanks.

Comment: That is way different from what you had initially asked for : "*The ideal solution would produce an index (depth) of 503 for the first occurrence of x1, 502 for the first occurrence of x2, and 504 for the last occurrence of x3*" according to this :-you didnt mention anything about an expected dataframe with min and max valid indexes.

Comment: Apologies to anky_91 for not specifying extra tasks.  Main challenge I had was getting the indexes.  Having the output as a dataframe is a convenient bonus.  I'm grateful to see your and others' approaches to the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this, if I understand you correctly:

```
pd.concat([df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index),
           df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)], 
           axis=1, 
           keys=['Min_Depth', 'Max_Depth'])
```

Output:

```
      Min_Depth   Max_Depth
x1          503         505
x2          502         505
x3          500         504
```

Or Transpose output:

```
pd.concat([df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index),
           df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)], 
           axis=1, 
           keys=['Min_Depth', 'Max_Depth']).T
```

Output:

```
            x1   x2   x3
Min_Depth  503  502  500
Max_Depth  505  505  504
```

---

Using apply with a list of func:

```
df.apply([pd.Series.first_valid_index, pd.Series.last_valid_index])
```

Output:

```
                    x1   x2   x3
first_valid_index  503  502  500
last_valid_index   505  505  504
```

With a little renaming:

```
df.apply([pd.Series.first_valid_index, pd.Series.last_valid_index])\
  .set_axis(['Min_Depth', 'Max_Depth'], axis=0, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
            x1   x2   x3
Min_Depth  503  502  500
Max_Depth  505  505  504
```

Answer (score 5):

[first_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html)() and last_valid_index() can be used.

```
    >>> df
             x1    x2    x3
    Depth
    500     NaN   NaN  25.0
    501     NaN   NaN  27.0
    502     NaN  33.0  24.0
    503     4.0  32.0  18.0
    504    12.0  45.0   5.0
    505     8.0  38.0   NaN
    >>> df["x1"].first_valid_index()
    503
    >>> df["x2"].first_valid_index()
    502
    >>> df["x3"].first_valid_index()
    500
    >>> df["x3"].last_valid_index()
    504
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) :

```
df.notna().agg({'x1':'idxmax','x2':'idxmax','x3':lambda x: x[::-1].idxmax()})
#df.notna().agg({'x1':'idxmax','x2':'idxmax','x3':lambda x: x[x].last_valid_index()})
```

---

```
x1    503
x2    502
x3    504
```

Another way would be to check if first row is nan and according to that apply the condition:

```
np.where(df.iloc[0].isna(),df.notna().idxmax(),df.notna()[::-1].idxmax())
```

---

```
[503, 502, 504]
```

Comment: I think OP want to automatically detect which column applied `[::-1].idxmax()` and which just `idxmax()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang added another solution based on that

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).head(1)
Out[619]: 
Depth    
500    x3    25.0
502    x2    33.0
503    x1     4.0
dtype: float64
```